# Can anyone tel me how to set target line in crystal report in crystal report 8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Iam a newbie to crystal report.Can anyone tel me Adding a Target Line to Bar Chart programmatically in crystal report(crystal report 8) using visual studio 2008.

Target line is shown in image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

quoted from http://www.maximumimpactsolutions.co.uk/blog/comments.asp?bd=125

Create the chart as required
Select the Y-axis of the chart
Right click on the Y-axis, select the menu option Data (Y) Axis
In the Data (Y) Axis Setting dialog box, click on the Gridlines Tab
Add a tick to the Draw Custom Line at option
Add the required value in the text box
Press the OK button

To format the Target Line:

Select the Target Line
Right click on the Target Line, select the menu option Format User Line
In the Format User Line Dialog Box, apply the required formatting
Press the OK button

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this in the Crystal Report Designer would be:

- Add a new Formula field, called something like `target`, with the required target value.
- Right-click on the Chart and select Chart Expert.
- In the Data tab of the Chart Expert dialog, select your new `target` formula and click on the `>` button next to the 'Show value(s)' list. The `@target` field should be added to the list of values, without a summary operation being specified.
- Click on OK at the bottom of the Chart Expert dialog and preview the report - a line for the target value should now appear on the report.